# Calendario con HTML y JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando este calendario con JavaScript, la maquetación es la correcta y hace todo bien, pero no consigo hacer que me saque los días de cada mes de manera correcta.

Necesito detectar también en que mes y día estoy y en el cuadro blanco al hacer click poder añadir evento ya con ese día y mes.

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Array con los nombres de los días de la semana
    var daysOfWeek = ['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mié', 'jue', 'vie', 'sáb'];

    // Función para obtener el nombre del día de la semana
    function getDayName(year, month, day) {
        var dayOfWeekIndex = new Date(year, month, day).getDay();
        return daysOfWeek[dayOfWeekIndex];
    }

    // Obtener el cuerpo de la tabla
    var calendarBody = document.getElementById('calendarBody');

    // Generar las filas para cada día del mes
    for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');

        // Generar las celdas para cada día del año
        for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
            var daysInMonth = new Date(2024, month + 1, 0).getDate();
            // Comprobar si el día es válido para el mes actual
            if (day <= daysInMonth) {
                var currentDay = new Date(2024, month, day);
                var cell = document.createElement('td');
                cell.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="CalendarCell CalendarCell--editable">
                        <div class="CalendarCell-dayNumber">${currentDay.getDate()}</div>
                        <div class="CalendarCell-dayName">${getDayName(2024, month, day)}</div>
                        <div class="CalendarCell-eventSocketWrapper">
                            <div class="CalendarEventSocket">
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-emptyClickArea"></div>
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-overflow" style="display: none;">+0</div>
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-selectionOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
        }

        // Agregar la fila a la tabla
        calendarBody.appendChild(row);
    }
});
```

```css
.CalendarGrid {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
.CalendarGrid-mask {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.CalendarGrid-table {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: relative;
}
.CalendarHeaderCell {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.CalendarHeaderCell-inner, .CalendarHeaderCell-inner > a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -o-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -o-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #444;
}
.CalendarGrid-table td {
    padding: 0;
}
.CalendarCell {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 22px;
}
.CalendarCell-dayNumber {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.CalendarCell-dayName {
    width: 50px;
    color: #9a9999;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.CalendarCell-eventSocketWrapper {
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CalendarGrid">
   <div class="CalendarGrid-mask" style="width: 4000px;">
      <table class="CalendarGrid-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">enero</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">febrero</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">marzo</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">abril</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">mayo</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">junio</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">julio</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">agosto</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">septiembre</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">octubre</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">noviembre</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">diciembre</div></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="calendarBody">
      
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes un pequeño error, que es cuando el día supera la cantidad de días del mes, por ejemplo 30 de febrero.

En este `if`

```
if (day <= daysInMonth) {
```

Tu dices que cuando el día es correcto lo imprima en pantalla (agregue una celda), pero y **¿cuando no lo es?**. Al estar usando una `table` para ingresar los días, no puedes dejar una celda sin ingresar. Entonces a lo menos, debes ingresar una celda vacía cuando el día sobre pasa los días del mes

```
if (day <= daysInMonth) {
  //tu código
}
else{
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  row.appendChild(cell);           
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Array con los nombres de los días de la semana
    var daysOfWeek = ['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mié', 'jue', 'vie', 'sáb'];

    // Función para obtener el nombre del día de la semana
    function getDayName(year, month, day) {
        var dayOfWeekIndex = new Date(year, month, day).getDay();
        return daysOfWeek[dayOfWeekIndex];
    }

    // Obtener el cuerpo de la tabla
    var calendarBody = document.getElementById('calendarBody');

    // Generar las filas para cada día del mes
    for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');

        // Generar las celdas para cada día del año
        for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
            var daysInMonth = new Date(2024, month + 1, 0).getDate();
            // Comprobar si el día es válido para el mes actual
            
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            if (day > daysInMonth){
               cell.innerHTML = `<div class="CalendarCell CalendarCell--editable">
                        <div class="CalendarCell-dayNumber"></div>
                        <div class="CalendarCell-dayName"></div>
                        <div class="CalendarCell-eventSocketWrapper">
                            <div class="CalendarEventSocket">
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-emptyClickArea"></div>
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-overflow" style="display: none;">+0</div>
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-selectionOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
            }
            else  {
                var currentDay = new Date(2024, month, day);
                
                cell.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="CalendarCell CalendarCell--editable">
                        <div class="CalendarCell-dayNumber">${currentDay.getDate()}</div>
                        <div class="CalendarCell-dayName">${getDayName(2024, month, day)}</div>
                        <div class="CalendarCell-eventSocketWrapper">
                            <div class="CalendarEventSocket">
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-emptyClickArea"></div>
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-overflow" style="display: none;">+0</div>
                                <div class="CalendarEventSocket-selectionOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
                
            }
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        // Agregar la fila a la tabla
        calendarBody.appendChild(row);
    }
});
```

```css
.CalendarGrid {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
.CalendarGrid-mask {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.CalendarGrid-table {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: relative;
}
.CalendarHeaderCell {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.CalendarHeaderCell-inner, .CalendarHeaderCell-inner > a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -o-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -o-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #444;
}
.CalendarGrid-table td {
    padding: 0;
}
.CalendarCell {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 22px;
}
.CalendarCell-dayNumber {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.CalendarCell-dayName {
    width: 50px;
    color: #9a9999;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.CalendarCell-eventSocketWrapper {
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CalendarGrid">
   <div class="CalendarGrid-mask" style="width: 4000px;">
      <table class="CalendarGrid-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">enero</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">febrero</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">marzo</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">abril</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">mayo</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">junio</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">julio</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">agosto</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">septiembre</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">octubre</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">noviembre</div></th>
            <th class="CalendarHeaderCell"><div class="CalendarHeaderCell-inner">diciembre</div></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="calendarBody">
      
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Estupendo, gracias @Yussef , te suena de ver este tipo de calendario en algún repositorio, o sigo construyendo?? Saludos

Comment: @Miguel Hace ya varios años yo construí un calendario y con él aprendí bastante cosas del ámbito cultural, los años bisiestos , semanas del años, estándar ISO, contar días, etc. Quizás no sea cosas muy útiles , pero a lo menos a mi me resultaron interesantes. Por otro lado, yo estoy en contra de usar componentes de 3ros (a menos que me tome mucho tiempo desarrollarlo yo mismo), es decir solo para casos excepcionales.  Te animo a que sigas construyendo tu propio calendario, seguro que sacaras cosas interesantes de la experiencia. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por el consejo @Yussef normalmente lo programo todo yo sin utilizar nada de nadie, pero me parecia más completo hacer lo del calendario, así que voy a seguir con ello. Mil gracias!